# how to hide link when content is empty?

Tags: jquery

I have created a example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/TFBqf/7/

This is not working:

```
var a = $("#content div:empty").html("").css("background","red");

if(a) {
    $("#link").hide;
}else{
    $("#link").show;
    return;
}
```

Comment: .hide should be .hide().  Also, if(a) should probably be if(a.size())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is: http://jsfiddle.net/TFBqf/18/

try to remove text in div to check it

```
var a = $("#content div").html("");

if(a.length == 0) {
    $("#link").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually executing the `.show` and `.hide` methods...

Should be:

```
if(a) {
    $("#link").hide();
}else{
    $("#link").show();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(a) {
    $('#link').hide(); // instead of .hide;
}else{
    $('#link').show(); // instead of .show;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/TFBqf/14/

You were actually checking the wrong thing and use the `show` method for both cases (without the use of parenthesis also).

```
var a = $("#content div").html();
```

This will return the actual content of your div.

Answer (score 0):

Works:

```
$('#link')[$('#content:empty').length ? 'show' : 'hide']();
```